# Get file contents by commit hash using Octokit

Tags: github, npm, octokit

I am unable to get the file contents of a given commit hash. I get the current file version from the default branch no matter the hash I have for ref.

My only guess is that the ref cannot be a plain hash, but the [documentation](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#api-Repos-getContent) describes the 'ref' as, "The name of the commit/branch/tag." and gives no further instruction on formatting.

I replicated the issue with a runkit [here](https://runkit.com/mriess260/5b43a80ab034eb0012c5a245). And provided the code from my actual project below.

```
async getDifference(): Promise<void> {
    let oldFile = await this.gitHubApi.getContent(this.repo.owner.login, this.repo.name, `./${this.file}`, this.oldHash);
    let newFile = await this.gitHubApi.getContent(this.repo.owner.login, this.repo.name, `./${this.file}`, this.newHash);
    if(oldFile.data.content === newFile.data.content) {
        console.log('no differencce');
    } else {
       ...
    }
    return;
}


public getContent(owner: string, repo: string, path: string, ref?: string): Promise<any> {
    if(ref) {
        return this.octokit.repos.getContent({
            owner: owner,
            repo: repo,
            path: path,
            ref: ref
        });
    } else {
        return this.octokit.repos.getContent({
            owner: owner,
            repo: repo,
            path: path
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case there's anything obvious, can you show us the code where you're calling Octokit with the commit hash? Or the REST URL that it's generating and requesting? Thanks.

Comment: OK, thanks. Are you sure the `if(ref)` branch is being taken? FWIW I've just tried the API myself with one of my repos and (without actually checking the compressed content) ref does make a difference.

Comment: @Rup Yes, the if(ref) branch is being taken. I have a console.log there to be sure; I just omitted it in the provided code for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in octokit/rest, or unexpected behaviour at least, but arguably you're giving it bad input. From [your example](https://runkit.com/mriess260/5b43a80ab034eb0012c5a245):

```
path: './test.txt/'
```

Octokit doesn't like either the leading `./`, but will tolerate it if you provide a trailing slash. However the trailing slash is causing it to ignore the `ref` arg, i.e. `path: 'test.txt/'` fails with the same error you're seeing. (And is arguably wrong: the slash implies a folder, whereas this is just a file - why add the slash?) You really want

```
path: 'test.txt'
```

It might be worth raising an issue against octokit/rest, but if you strip the leading `./` and trailing `/`s from your paths it should work fine.

Incidentally, from your comments

> note that the object 'sha's are the same, and that neither match the provided 'ref' hash.

That's to be expected: the ref provided is for the commit, which is a hash of the commit metadata and root tree, which is a hash of the root folder index, and that's what contains the object SHA hash.

Comment: Oh I see you have raised an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/944

Comment: That did it. It was a combination of a stupid mistake on my part and a weird bug. Also thanks for letting me know about the hashes; I just assumed that the sha in the response object was the commit hash.